# Working with number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How could I do this?

```
1 -> 01
4 -> 04
9 -> 09
11 -> 11
22 -> 22
```

Thanks!

Comment: Using strings or octal numbers. Do you want this for sorting issues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a duplicate of [610406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format). The simple thing, if you only want to add a 0 to numbers less than 10 would be something like:

```
function formatNum(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
        return '0' + num;
    }

    return num + '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = myNumber.toString(10);
if(myint < 10)
{
  result = "0" + result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 9;
i = "0" + i;
i = i.substring(i.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something flexible:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(length){
    return (new Array(length - this.toString().length + 1)).join('0') + this;
}

var x = 6;
x.pad(2); // 06
```

or if you want the basic 2-digit only:

```
x<10 ? '0'+x : x
```